# EncryptDescrypt Frida game unity

Tags: javascript, frida

I'm trying to find out if the protection from game of me friend really works.His game is made by the Unity engine, I decompiled the game and to my surprise, some strings are encrypted, others are not. So to decide if the protection is working, I scoured the game's dex, I found something interesting:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNgic.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BFfc.png)

I thought of something like:

> if(paramArrayOfbyte1 ==
> Base64.decode("bAcSdZ85r6jkMZr4GbKC1N9WEQp5j66DEg==")){
> PRINT(Base64.encodeToString(paramArrayOfbyte2)); }

but it doesn't work, can anyone help me?(i using frida)

Comment: what is your friend trying to protect against? how is he doing it and what's the rationale for the approach?

Comment: Please post the frida hooking code you have so far.